# system backup with dual-boot (Paragon ?)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, backup

I´ve got a question concerning system backup of a dual-boot system.

Currently I´ve got WIN 8.1 home (64bit) installed on my computer.
I´m thinking of changing that to a dual-boot system (WIN 8.1 + Ubuntu) on the same disk (HD). On different partitions of course.

Now I´m looking for a backup programme capable of creating system backups in such a way that my two operating systems would be saved and could easily be restored to the original state of my disk (WIN 8.1 + Ubuntu).

Plus that backup programme should be freeware if possible.

I found Paragon Backup & Recovery 14 Free Edition and 
Supported File Systems are:

```
NTFS (v1.2, v3.0, v3.1)
FAT16
FAT32
Linux Ext2FS
Linux Ext3FS
Linux Ext4FS
Linux Swap
Limited read/write access to Apple HFS+ partitions
Other file systems (in the sector-by-sector mode)
```

Link: http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/requirements.html

My question now is:
would that be the right programme for my purposes or does anyone know a backup programme that meets my demands?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Season´s Greetings

Rosika

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu you could use the 'dd' command to clone your drive byte for byte to an external drive. you will need to run this off a live cd.

I know linking off site is not recommended, but you can get a better explanation here and from other ubuntu/linux forums on stack exchange, etc...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/246921/is-my-command-to-clone-a-drive-optimal

Comment: Clearly your link seems interesting. Thanks for that. I just wonder about Paragon though, as they refer to "ext4" and "swap" as supported file formats. Yet the  "dd" command might be an alternative though I believe there´s no possibility of compressing the generated file.

Comment: You could also look into Macrium Free backup edition

Do you have another Hard drive? You could also just mirror your current hard drive onto another.

Comment: I definitely will have a closer look into Macrium Free. Thanks for the suggestion. In the meantime I found an article "Freeware to Backup Windows 7 and Ubuntu Dual Boot System" which promotes Aomei Bachupper Free. There´s also a reference to WIN 8.1 + Ubuntu. Link: http://www.backup-utility.com/res/backup-windows-7-ubuntu-dual-boot-system-4348.html . I wonder whether that might work.

Comment: I'll take a look, i've never heard of the software but it does look appealing. I'm willing to try it out on my home device just to see how it performs.

Comment: Aomei has a rather good reputation as far as I know. Besides it´s the only freeware programme that is able to restore to dissimilar hardware. Link: https://davescomputertips.com/aomei-backupper-now-includes-restore-to-dissimilar-hardware-for-free/ . P.S.: The latest version is 3.2